# What does betweenness mean?

Tags: computational-complexity

For some reason i could not find a working example on the theory of betweenness.What does betweenness mean when we are talking in terms of ordering problem ?

Comment: See [Betweenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness).

Comment: Let $\leq$ be a ordering on a set $X$. Then $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ iff $a\leq b\leq c$.